# In which column there is a value of a specific variable

Tags: r, col

I have this dataframe:

```
a <- c(2,5,90,77,56,65,85,75,12,24,52,32)
b <- c(45,78,98,55,63,12,23,38,75,68,99,73)
c <- c(77,85,3,22,4,69,86,39,78,36,96,11)
d <- c(52,68,4,25,79,120,97,20,7,19,37,67)
e <- c(14,73,91,87,94,38,1,685,47,102,666,74)

df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e)
```

and this variable:

```
bb <- 120
```

I need to know the column number of df in which there is the value of the variable "bb". How can I do?
Thx everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `which` with `arr.ind = TRUE` to extract the row/col index after creating a logical matrix.  Then, extract the second column to get the column index

```
which(df == bb, arr.ind = TRUE)[,2]
col 
  4
```

If there are duplicate elements in the column for the value compared, wrap with `unique` to return the unique column index

```
unique(which(df == bb, arr.ind = TRUE)[,2])
[1] 4
```

Answer (score 3):

I think we could use `grep`

```
grep(bb, df)
[1] 4
```